# how reactjs updates all the changes in dom in single event loop to paint dom only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, layout, event-loop

I was reading article about dom update in reactjs.Reactjs updates all the changes in single event loop.I understand event loop in javascript and how it works in core javascript.Can any one tell how reactjs uses event loop for dom manipulation

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/dom-manipulation-in-react

Answer (score 0):

React has a Virtual DOM, doesn't manipulate the DOM directly.

The Virtual DOM is a copy of the HTML DOM and is local to React. We can call it an abstraction of the HTML DOM. So, whatever changes need to be made to the DOM, React does that to this Virtual DOM and syncs the Real DOM accordingly.

React will update the entire Virtual DOM.

When we call the render() method it’ll compare the Virtual DOM before updating, with the one after updating, to identify what objects have been changed. It uses the Diffing Algorithm.

Then compare the Virtual DOM with the real one, and only the changed objects will get updated on the real DOM.

Comment: As much I know react always has a copy of virtual dom in memory.When we call set state on any component it creates new virtual dom and compare old with new virtual dom and update the virtual dom with the new changes.But as you say "Then compare the Virtual DOM with the real one, and only the changed objects will get updated on the real DOM."s there any step where real dom and virtual dom is compared?

Comment: Everything is happening when render() method is called. When the render() method is executed, it comperes the old virtual DOM with the new virtual DOM. If  there's any changes, update the virtual DOM and then compare the virtual DOM with the real one. If there's any differences, it reach out the real DOM and update it, but NOT entirely. Only changes in the places where the differences were detected. For example: if wi change only one paragraph, it will update only the paragraph, not entire real DOM. If doesn't find difference between Virtual DOM and the real one doesn't touch the real DOM